# The determinant of a matrix that has ones, where the sum of the indices is prime.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, determinant

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer and let $A = (a_{i, j})$ The matrix A is defined as follows

$a_{i,j}=1\;$ if $\;i + j\;$ is prime, $\;0$ otherwise.

For example for $\,n=2$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How to proof that, $|\det(A)| = k^2$ for some integer $k\,$?

My idea: figure it out somehow using mathematical induction. It is enough that the determinant is different from zero. So rather a matrix of $0$s and $1$s will have a determinant that is an integer, but I'm not good at algebra.

Comment: For which $n$ did you test this? It sounds pretty crazy to me that the determinant would always be a square, given the unpredictable nature of primes

Comment: However if this is indeed true, then my gut feeling is that it is true for all 0-1 matrices where the 1' occur along anti-diagonals (i.e. diagonals running north-east to south-west, as opposed to 'ordinary' diagonals that run north-west to south-east) and that the primes are a red herring

Comment: BTW: what do you mean by 'It is enough that the determinant is different from zero.'? There are **many** integers that are different from zero that are not of the form $k^2$.  How do you relate the two cases?